# How to set MergeOption = OverwriteChanges globally?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, orm, dbcontext

Our WinForms application has various dialogs & screens open each with their own DbContext. Often we want a screen to reload its data or part of its data which was modified on a diferent form with different DbContext, simply by re-executing the query against the database. By default, MergeOption = PreserveChanges therefore the database changes are not reflected in the DbContext.

Options we have considered:

**Call Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins) for relevant objects**

```
ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, models)
```

This is klutzy with rich complex model structures & collections as it must be called individually on each model.

**Set the MergeOption individually on every query**

```
((ObjectQuery)query).MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges
```

This works but has to be done manually every query which is easy to forget.

**Various manual hack through reflection**

Several SO pages suggest hacks like this however with EF7 on the horizon and the general riskiness I don't want to go down this path.

**QUESTION:** How can I set MergeOption=OverwriteChanges for everything in a DbContext? Or even better, globally?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN on [OverwriteChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.mergeoption(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
All current values on the client are overwritten with current values from the data service regardless of whether they have been changed on the client.
```

If you want to reload everything, drop the context and reload data again. This is the safest and fastest way to reload all data.

If you want to do the same for all DbContext instances in application, you need to do the same for each instance.

Edit: As far as setting the default MergeOption for each query you execute, to my knowledge thias is not possible. It seems that old trick to use reflection on ObjectContext to get all ObjectQueries does not work with DbContext. One possible option is to improve a little code you are using and wrap it into a method that will always apply OverwriteChanges, something like:

```
protected ObjectSet<T> GetObjectSet<T>() where T : class
{
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext;
    ObjectSet<T> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    set.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;

    return set;
}
```

and call this method instead of Context.Set().

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a T4 based solution to the EF oversight around `MergeOption` not being accessible in `DbSet`

In the default `DataContext` you have something generated Entity DBSets generated by the T4 template:

```
public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
etc.
```

Edit the template to add `IQueryable` getters for each `Entity`:

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetPersons(MergeOption mergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly, bool useQueryImplentation = true) 
{ 
    return useQueryImplementation ? GetSet<Person>(mergeOption).QueryImplementation() : GetSet<Person>(mergeOption); 
}
```

Then in a base `DataContext`

```
public class DataContextBase
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the forced MergeOption. When this is set all queries 
    /// generated using GetObjectSet will use this value
    /// </summary>
    public MergeOption? MergeOption { get; set; }


   /// <summary>
   /// Gets an ObjectSet of type T optionally providing a MergeOption.
   /// <remarks>Warning: if a DataContext.MergeOption is specified it will take precedence over the passed value</remarks>
   /// </summary>
   /// <typeparam name="TEntity">ObjectSet entity Type</typeparam>
   /// <param name="mergeOption">The MergeOption for the query (overriden by DataContext.MergeOption)</param>
   protected IQueryable<TEntity> GetObjectSet<TEntity>(MergeOption? mergeOption = null) where TEntity : class
   {
      var set = Context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
      set.MergeOption = MergeOption ?? mergeOption ?? MergeOption.AppendOnly;

      return set;
   }
```

By creating a default Extension method for an `IQueryable` as below you can optionally add your own implenations of `QueryImplementation<T>` for each table/type so that all users of your table get sorting or includes etc. 
(not required to answer the question but its useful)

So for example you could add the following to always Include Addresses when calling `GetPersons()`

```
 public static class CustomQueryImplentations
 {
        public static IQueryable<Person> QueryImplementation(this IQueryable<Person> source)
        {
            return source
                .Include(r => r.Addresses)
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Name);
        }
  }
```

### **Usage**

Load a simple list with no tracking (Fast!)

```
var people = Database.GetPersons(MergeOption.NoTracking);
```

Edit `Person`, attached and updated with latest db values (Slow)

```
var peson = Database.GetPersons(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges).FirstOrDefault(p => p.PersonID = 1);
```

On another machine:

```
var people = Database.GetPersons(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

Alternatively, to answer your original question to set `MergeOption` globally

```
Database.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

Get entities using existing get methods...

```
Database.MergeOption = null;
```

**Note:** Something to be carefull about is that if you load `MergeOption.AsNoTracking` before you make changes you need to either attach or better reload with `MergeOption.OverwriteChanges` to ensure you have the latest Entity.